# Storing Dialogbox EditText into database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, dialog

So I have a dialog box, where `EditText` is enabled, and when someone keys in something, and clicks on the add button, their text gets added into the database. Here are my "mainactivity" which is named `IndivItem.java`, codes.

```
public class IndivItem extends Activity {

TextView name, price;
Button descB, revB;
ImageView converse;
ImageButton fav, buy, compare;
TableLayout table_layout;
ReviewController revcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indiv_item);

    revcon = new ReviewController(this);

    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.picPrice1);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    descB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    revB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.review);

    converse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shoee1);

    fav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fv1);
    buy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.co1);
    compare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cp1);

    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    BuildTable();

    revB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    IndivItem.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title

            alertDialog.setTitle("Review");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Add a Review");
            final EditText input = new EditText(IndivItem.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            alertDialog
                    .setView(input)

                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })

                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {

                                    new MyAsync().execute();

                                    // toast saying review added
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Review Added!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent home = new Intent(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            IndivItem.class);
                                    startActivity(home);

                                }

                                // close dialog
                            });

            // show alert
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });



    fav.setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(IndivItem.this, "Add to Favorites",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });

    compare.setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onHover(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(IndivItem.this, "Add to Compare List",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });

}

private void BuildTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    revcon.open();
    Cursor c = revcon.readEntry();

    int rows = c.getCount();
    int cols = c.getColumnCount();

    c.moveToFirst();

    // outer for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(IndivItem.this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // inner for loop
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            TextView tv = new TextView(IndivItem.this);

            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextSize(18);
            tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

            tv.setText(c.getString(j));

            row.addView(tv);

        }

        c.moveToNext();

        table_layout.addView(row);

    }
    revcon.close();

}

 private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String review = input.getText().toString();
        return null;

        revcon.open();
        revcon.createEntry(review);
           // BuildTable();

        return null;
    }}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And what happens is this line : `String review = input.getText().toString();`,
Gives me an error, that says error cannot resolved. I have no clue how to link the codes ): or what I'm doing wrong, please enlighten me,thanks!

Comment: input is not available in asynctask. You have it declared and initialized in `onClick` `final EditText input = new EditText(IndivItem.this);` You can get the text from editText when you click the dialog button and do `new MyAsync().execute(input.getText().toString());`. and in asynctask doInbackground use `arg[0]`

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't creating your AsyncTask in a way that you can pass the data to the doInBackground method?

Comment: Do what Raghunandan suggests, and declare MyTask like this:

    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>

Comment: @Raghunandan Hi i dont quite get this part, 'and in asynctask doInbackground use arg[0]', where am I supposed to change this? thank you very much!!

Comment: @PLEASEHELPMEE In `doInBackground`  have `String value= argo[0]`. Use value in whatever way you deem fit. `argo[0]` corresponds to `input.getText().toString()` which you pass to `doInBackground` by having `new MyAsync().execute(input.getText().toString());`

Comment: @LeeWallen I followed an online tutorial on something similar! Therefore I'm not that sure about the way the AsyncTask is created ): and thanks for the suggestion! I will try it now!

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you very much! It is displayed now, Thank you!! Have a nice day!(:

Comment: @PLEASEHELPMEE - I know you have it resolved it now, but you might find it helpful to read through the AsyncTask information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The reason you might find it helpful is that you can also declare return types from the AsyncTask (as well as progress update data types).  So, imagine that you saved a review (the String) to a database, and wanted to return an ID for the record.  You could define the MyAsync like this:

    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, void, int> 

where the third data type (int) is the return type.